AOSP granted REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES
I'm encountering an issue when integrating the application into the AOSP as the application requires the REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission.
Is there any way to grant this permission to the application by default without having to rebuild the APK with the platform signature?

To grant the permissions by default, you need to have a etc/default-permissions.xml setup.
Please refer to sample here: https://android.googlesource.com/device/google/marlin/+/nougat-dr1-release/default-permissions.xml

Thank you for your response. Signing the APK with the platform signature would indeed solve the problem. However, I want to retain the partner's original signature.
